# Doing full text search with elasticsearch firestore and react-native

Tags: firebase, elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a question regarding how to do a full-text search on firestore. I have a simple app, which I wrote on react native. My app works fine, I have cloud functions, which get triggered onCreate, onEdit, etc.

I would like to integrate Elastic Search. As per [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search?provider=elastic) docs and [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-getting-started-node-js.html#ec_ingest_data) doc, there is no package, which I can install to connect directly to Elasticsearch from react-native app. I need to write a proxy server (on node.js) which I need to connect to firebase (so that my firebase functions will get called when I create a document when I edit it etc...) My firebase functions will now do two things:

1. the actions which they did now when I was creating a document (e.g.
   increment count); these are the actions, they did from my react
   native project
2. they will also replicate data to elastic search service so that I will be able to do a full-text search

Am I correct in my understanding?
My next question is, how do I connect to the node js proxy server via my react native app? I am writing a mobile app, and I want to publish it to the google play store. How can I publish it when it will depend on the proxy server (written on node js)? Do I need to publish the proxy server somewhere else as well?

Basically, I am struggling to understand how my react native app will call the proxy server.

**EDIT**: I thought it will be a good idea to put this link as a reference - basically my starting point was to install `@elastic/elasticsearch` package and to use it directly from my react native app. I run into many problems, and after some digging, I found a discussion [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/1677) where people explain why you can not use `@elastic/elasticsearch` package with react native and they suggest using a proxy server.

Hence why I was asking about connecting my app to a proxy server. As I wrote in the comments (as per my understanding) this proxy server will serve two funcionts:

1. All my cloud functions (which are now located into my react nativ project) will be moved into this proxy server, so that the server will listen for changes like `onCreate`, `onEdit`, etc,... **AND** if the function is called, the server will sync my data with elasticsearch
2. The server will provide me with the `/search/` endpoints
   which I will call from my react native app.

Am I correct in my understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Note**: While this anwser is fully based on Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search?provider=elastic) it is advised to use the corresponding [Search with Elastic App Search](https://extensions.dev/extensions/elastic/firestore-elastic-app-search) Firebase Extension instead of implementing it yourself. The extension will help you deploy this functionality much quicker as it is a pre-packaged solution.*

> How do I connect to the node js proxy server via
> my react native app? I am writing a mobile app, and I want to publish
> it to the google play store. How can I publish it when it will depend
> on the proxy server (written on node js)? Do I need to publish the
> proxy server somewhere else as well?

As shown in the example from Firebase [documentation you refer to](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search?provider=elastic), there are two Cloud Functions to implement (I copy the example code below for reference.):

1. The `onNoteCreated` Cloud Function is triggered every time a blog post is written and it calls Elastic Search to update the search index
2. The `searchNotes` Cloud Function is a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) that is called **from your application**, ans which calls Elastic Search to search the index and returns the result to your app

Note that **all** the blocks marked "Node.js" in the example included in the doc (a note-taking app where each note is a document) are to be included in your Cloud Function `index.js` file.  And you can very well add your own current code to the `onCreate` Firestore triggered Cloud Function.

In other words, what you refer to as "the proxy server" in your question can be fully implemented in Cloud Functions and there is actually no need to manage and scale your own server.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const { Client } = require("@elastic/elasticsearch");

// Initialize Elastic, requires installing Elastic dependencies:
// https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js
//
// ID, username, and password are stored in functions config variables
const ELASTIC_ID = functions.config().elastic.id;
const ELASTIC_USERNAME = functions.config().elastic.username;
const ELASTIC_PASSWORD = functions.config().elastic.password;

const client = new Client({
  cloud: {
    id: ELASTIC_ID,
    username: ELASTIC_USERNAME,
    password: ELASTIC_PASSWORD,
  }
});


// Update the search index every time a blog post is written.
exports.onNoteCreated = functions.firestore.document('notes/{noteId}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
  // Get the note document
  const note = snap.data();

  // Use the 'nodeId' path segment as the identifier for Elastic
  const id = context.params.noteId;

  // Write to the Elastic index
  client.index({
    index: "notes",
    id,
    body: note,
  });
});

exports.searchNotes = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const query = data.query;

  // Search for any notes where the text field contains the query text.
  // For more search examples see:
  // https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/search_examples.html
  const searchRes = await client.search({
    index: "notes",
    body: {
      query: {
        query_string: {
          query: `*${query}*`,
          fields: [
            "text"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // Each entry will have the following properties:
  //   _score: a score for how well the item matches the search
  //   _source: the original item data
  const hits = searchRes.body.hits.hits;

  const notes = hits.map(h => h["_source"]);
  return {
    notes: notes
  };
});
```

Comment: Does this solution better or equivalent to [**Search with Elastic App Search**](https://extensions.dev/extensions/elastic/firestore-elastic-app-search) Extension in terms of cost or feature parity ?

Comment: It is equivalent at a basic level. However the Extension is probably more robust in terms of error handling (I didn't dive into the code but usually Extensions are covering all the possible cases). Also the doc explains that "You’ll also have tooling so your team can easily track and tweak search relevance based on usage data." I advise to  go for the extension.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This solves my concern about going with the Extension route or writing it custom.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Thanks for your answer but I believe this is not true: "you have to call, from your application, the Callable Cloud Function that search the index and returns the result to your app." I can not use `const { Client } = require("@elastic/elasticsearch");` inside a react native project. As discussed here https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/1677 the package can not be used with react native, so the devs suggest using a proxy server.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec So I though maybe I need to move my firebase functions (onCreate, onEdit, onDelete) from my react native app to my proxy server? Connect the proxy server to my firestore instance, so it listens for changes AND it updates the data in elasticsearch. Also I need to use the proxy for queries like "search". Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: You should not use the Elasticsearch Node.js client in your React application but in the Cloud Function. The code in my answer (from the Firebase doc) **is Cloud Function code** not React . The `onNoteCreated` CF call  Elastic Search to update the search index. And the app call the `searchNotes` Cloud Function which, in turns, call ElasticSearch. So there are 2 Cloud Functions, one triggered in the background and one that is called by your app. No need for any proxy. You may read again the documentation for Callable Cloud Functions.